# Ошибка при сохранении JSONField в django

Tags: json, django

У меня есть такое вот поле в модели:

```
    additional = JSONField(verbose_name='Дополнительно', null=True)
```

И при попытке сохранить объект выскакивает вот такая ошибка

```
Error binding parameter 7 - probably unsupported type.
```

Пользуюсь SQLite, возможно из-за него?
Заношу данные в формате: {"a":"b"}

Comment: В документации очень большими буквами написано "PostgreSQL specific model field".

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, да я уже понял)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 5.7.8+ поставляется с собственным типом данных JSON . Вы можете добавить его в свой проект Django с помощью пакета django-mysql и Django 2+.

```
pip install django-mysql
```

Узнайте больше о JSONField django_mysql [здесь](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html#jsonfield) .

```
from django.db import models
from django_mysql.models import JSONField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_json_field = JSONField()
```